# Mostrar div oculto al pasar el cursor

Tags: javascript, php, xml

estoy intentando de hacer una guía de tv para web.
Estoy extrayendo el titulo y la descripción de los programas de un canal de tv desde un enlace XML.
Quiero que la descripción este oculta y que cuando paso el cursor encima del titulo se muestre.
Este es el código que estoy utilizando:

```
<head>
  <style>
    .progratitu2 {
cursor: pointer;
     }
    .progradesc2 {
display: none;
     }
    .progradesc2.activo {
display: block;
     }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <?php
     $url = 'https://iptv-org.github.io/epg/guides/at/tvheute.at.epg.xml';
     $xml=simplexml_load_file("$url"); 
     foreach($xml->xpath('programme[@channel="ATV.at"]') as $item) {
        echo '<div class="progratitu2" id="mosdesc">' .$item->title.'</div>';
        echo '<div class="progradesc2" id="desc">'.$item->desc.'</div>';
        echo "<br>";
     }
  ?> 
 <script>
   const mostrar = document.querySelector('#mosdesc');
   const descripcion = document.querySelector('#desc');

   mostrar.addEventListener('mouseenter', () => {
     descripcion.classList.add('activo');
   });

  mostrar.addEventListener('mouseleave', () => {
     descripcion.classList.remove('activo');
   });

  descripcion.addEventListener('mouseleave', () => descripcion.classList.remove('activo'));
</script>
```

el problema que tengo que solo me muestra la descripción del primer programa, el resto de programas solo se muestra el titulo pero al pasar el cursor no me muestra la descripción.
No tengo experiencia y me esta costando hacerlo, estaría muy agradecido si alguien podría ayudarme, Gracias.

Comment: No entiendo el enunciado ni lo que es que está pasando que no debería pasar

Comment: Estoy extrayendo una lista de programas (titulo y descripción) de un canal de tv. la descripción esta oculta y quiero que se muestre cuando paso el cursor encima del titulo. el problema que tengo que solo me muestra la descripción del primer programa, el resto de programas solo se muestra el titulo pero al pasar el cursor no me muestra la descripción.

Comment: @Myky, comentario, creo que sería una mejor idea usar `click` sobre los títulos para mostrar la descripción. Se me hace que así como está la experiencia del usuario (_UX_) no es muy amigable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Crear muchos elementos con el mismo 'id' es un error ya que al buscarlos sólo vas a encontrar el primero.

#### Solución:

Podrías crear un contenedor para el título y la descripción, y cuando el mouse pase sobre el título (*elemento visible*), al contenedor le agregas la clase `activo` y así mostrar la descripción.

**Ejemplo:**

```js
const programas = document.querySelectorAll('.progracont');
programas.forEach(e => {
  e.addEventListener('mouseover', () => {
    e.classList.add('activo');
  });

  e.addEventListener('mouseout', () => {
    e.classList.remove('activo');
  });
});
```

```css
.progratitu2 {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.progracont .progradesc2 {
  display: none;
}

.progracont.activo .progradesc2 {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="progracont">
  <div class="progratitu2">3satTextVision</div>
  <div class="progradesc2">Das Informationsangebot wird nachts zur programmfreien Sendezeit ausgestrahlt. Aktuelle Nachrichten sowie Wetter- und Sport-News werden dabei ebenso integriert wie das Sender-Programm des nächsten Tages.</div>
  <br>
</div>
<div class="progracont">
  <div class="progratitu2">Erlebnisreisen</div>
  <div class="progradesc2">Immer häufiger wird Instagram auch als Reiseführer genutzt. Aber können die schönen Bilder der Realität standhalten? Beim Check mit "#lookslike" in Tallinn, der Hauptstadt von Estland, hat Christian Loß die Hotspots und Geheimtipps der Stadt recherchiert
    und macht sich vor Ort ein Bild.</div>
  <br>
</div>
```

---

#### Actualización:

Haciendo clic, podría quedar así:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.progracont').forEach(e => {
  e.addEventListener('click', () => e.classList.toggle('activo'));
});
```

```css
.progratitu2 {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.progracont .progradesc2 {
  display: none;
}

.progracont.activo .progradesc2 {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="progracont">
  <div class="progratitu2">3satTextVision</div>
  <div class="progradesc2">Das Informationsangebot wird nachts zur programmfreien Sendezeit ausgestrahlt. Aktuelle Nachrichten sowie Wetter- und Sport-News werden dabei ebenso integriert wie das Sender-Programm des nächsten Tages.</div>
  <br>
</div>
<div class="progracont">
  <div class="progratitu2">Erlebnisreisen</div>
  <div class="progradesc2">Immer häufiger wird Instagram auch als Reiseführer genutzt. Aber können die schönen Bilder der Realität standhalten? Beim Check mit "#lookslike" in Tallinn, der Hauptstadt von Estland, hat Christian Loß die Hotspots und Geheimtipps der Stadt recherchiert
    und macht sich vor Ort ein Bild.</div>
  <br>
</div>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias Marcos, tu código funciona muy bien. Mi idea inicial, era la de reducir los click al máximo en ordenadores, a ver que tal funciona. Un saludo

Comment: Entiendo, mi comentario se basa principalmente en los saltos que genera mostrar y ocultar por solo mover el mouse. Imagina el caso en el que la descripción del programas es muy larga, moves el mouse hacia abajo y el salto que ocurre hacia arriba es muy grande, por lo que tenes que volver a ajustar la posición del puntero. Si la descripción estuviera "flotando" quizás no sería tan "molesto"

Comment: Tienes toda la razón, hacerlo flotante va ser la mejor solución. Muchas gracias

Comment: No veo la necesidad de complicarlo con JavaScript existiendo un conjunto en CSS que hace lo mismo

Comment: Hola Marcos, como puedo poner click para cerrar las descripciones? No consigo hacerlo.

Comment: @Myky, acabo de actualizar mi respuesta, para darte un ejemplo de cómo podrías hacerlo.

Comment: @DavidFernándezFlores, estoy un 100% de acuerdo con lo que comentas, es más uno de los votos en tu respuesta te lo di yo. Lo único que le falta es el caso de que no se oculte cuando moves el mouse sobre la descripción del programa

Comment: @Marcos muchas gracias, me estaba complicando la vida. Al final tenias razón, sin clicks queda un poco caótico, ni poniéndolo flotante. Seria posible que se cerrara el que esta abierto al clicar en otro titulo? muchas gracias

Comment: @Myky, sería tan simple como primero buscar el elemento `.progracont.active`, sacarle el `active` y luego agregar `active` al elemento click-eado

Comment: @Marcos ya lo tengo, ha quedado muy bien, muchas gracias por tu ayuda, eres un Crack.

Answer (score 3):

Para tener el comportamiento que deseas no es necesario utilizar JavaScript sino que se puede solucionar de forma más sencilla con CSS tal que:

```html
<head>
  <style>
    .progratitu2 {
       cursor: pointer;
     }
    .progradesc2 {
       display: none;
     }

    .progratitu2:hover + .progradesc2 {
       display: block;
     } 
  </style>
</head>
```

De esta manera al pasar el raton por encima de todos los elementos titulo con clase `progratitu2` se mostrará el elemento siguiente con clase `progradesc2` esto mediante el uso de la [pseudo-clase](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_pseudo_classes.asp) de CSS [`:hover`](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_hover.asp)

Comment: Muchas gracias David, es exactamente lo que buscaba. Muchas gracias por las respuestas. Un saludo